# Bomb lab Phase 4 Understanding

Tags: computer-science

I have been given the bomb lab assignment as a CS assignment and have reached phase 4.

I already understand how the phase 4 function is working and how it calls the func 4 function by passing on the inputs the user places through scan.

I needed a little help understanding what fun4 does.
Please could someone explain what the func 4 is attempting to do?

---

Dump of assembler code for function func4:

=> 0x08048af0 <+0>: push   %ebp

0x08048af1 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp

0x08048af3 <+3>: sub    $0x18,%esp

0x08048af6 <+6>: mov    %ebx,-0x8(%ebp)

0x08048af9 <+9>: mov    %esi,-0x4(%ebp)

0x08048afc <+12>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx

0x08048aff <+15>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax

0x08048b02 <+18>:    mov    0x10(%ebp),%ebx

0x08048b05 <+21>:    mov    %ebx,%ecx

0x08048b07 <+23>:    sub    %eax,%ecx

0x08048b09 <+25>:    mov    %ecx,%esi

0x08048b0b <+27>:    shr    $0x1f,%esi

0x08048b0e <+30>:    lea    (%esi,%ecx,1),%ecx

0x08048b11 <+33>:    sar    %ecx

0x08048b13 <+35>:    add    %eax,%ecx

0x08048b15 <+37>:    cmp    %edx,%ecx

0x08048b17 <+39>:    jle    0x8048b30

0x08048b19 <+41>:    sub    $0x1,%ecx

0x08048b1c <+44>:    mov    %ecx,0x8(%esp)

0x08048b20 <+48>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)

0x08048b24 <+52>:    mov    %edx,(%esp)

0x08048b27 <+55>:    call   0x8048af0

0x08048b2c <+60>:    add    %eax,%eax

0x08048b2e <+62>:    jmp    0x8048b50

0x08048b30 <+64>:    mov    $0x0,%eax

0x08048b35 <+69>:    cmp    %edx,%ecx

0x08048b37 <+71>:    jge    0x8048b50

0x08048b39 <+73>:    mov    %ebx,0x8(%esp)

0x08048b3d <+77>:    add    $0x1,%ecx

0x08048b40 <+80>:    mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)

0x08048b44 <+84>:    mov    %edx,(%esp)

0x08048b47 <+87>:    call   0x8048af0

0x08048b4c <+92>:    lea    0x1(%eax,%eax,1),%eax

0x08048b50 <+96>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%ebx

0x08048b53 <+99>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%esi

0x08048b56 <+102>:   mov    %ebp,%esp

0x08048b58 <+104>:   pop    %ebp

0x08048b59 <+105>:   ret

---

Thanks, it is much appreciated

Comment: From Help centre > Asking: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Thank you for alerting me webturner, I was not aware and have made the changes.